# AngularJS: ng-repeat across multilple divs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to have part of my website be a collage of images and information as shown below:

[image: My aim]

I can do this manually as a series of divs:

```
<div class="options">
    <div class="option">
        <a href="https://www.handpickedhotels.co.uk/bailbrookhouse"><img class="opt_img" src="images/hotels/BBH.jpg"></a>
        <h3 class="centered" id="hotel_info">Bailbrook House Hotel<br>BA1 7JD<br>Approx Price: &pound;xx</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        <a href="https://www.travelodge.co.uk/hotels/75/Bath-Central-hotel"><img class="opt_img" src="images/hotels/bath_central_travelodge.jpg"></a>
        <h3 class="centered" id="hotel_info">Bath Central Travelodge<br>BA1 2EB<br>Approx Price: &pound;xx </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        <a href="https://www.travelodge.co.uk/hotels/361/Bath-Waterside-hotel"><img class="opt_img" src="images/hotels/bath_waterside_travelodge.jpg"></a>
        <h3 class="centered" id="hotel_info">Bath Waterside Travelodge<br>BA2 4JP<br>Approx Price: &pound;xx</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="options">
    <div class="option">
        <a href="https://www.premierinn.com/gb/en/hotels/england/somerset/bath/bath-city-centre.html"><img class="opt_img" src="images/hotels/Bath_premier_inn.jpg"></a>
        <h3 class="centered" id="hotel_info">Bath City Centre Premier Inn<br>BA1 2BX<br>Approx Price: &pound;xx</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        <a href="https://www.yha.org.uk/hostel/yha-bath"><img class="opt_img" src="images/hotels/YHA.jpg"></a>
        <h3 class="centered" id="hotel_info">YHA Bath<br>BA2 6LA <br>Approx Price: &pound;xx </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        <a href="https://www.bailbrooklodge.co.uk/"><img class="opt_img" src="images/hotels/bailbrook_lodge.jpg"></a>
        <h3 class="centered" id="hotel_info">Bailbrook Lodge<br>BA1 7HZ<br>Approx Price: &pound;xx</h3>
    </div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
*{
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif
}

#hotel_info{
    background-color: rgba(130, 130, 130,0.7);
    width: 80%;
}

.centered {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.options{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.option {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 33%;
    float:left;
}

.opt_img{
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

I have now started playing with AngularJS as a way to more easily display this information.

I have MainController.js

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope){
    $scope.title = 'Hotels';
    $scope.hotels = [
        {
            name: 'Bailbrook House Hotel',
            postcode: "BA1 7JD",
            price: 0.00,
            website: "https://www.handpickedhotels.co.uk/bailbrookhouse",
            img: "images/hotels/BBH.jpg"
        },
        {
            name: "Bath Central Travelodge",
            postcode: "BA1 2EB",
            price: 0.00,
            website: "https://www.travelodge.co.uk/hotels/75/Bath-Central-hotel",
            img: "images/hotels/bath_central_travelodge.jpg"
        },
        {
            name: "Bath Waterside Travelodge",
            postcode: "BA2 4JP",
            price: 0.00,
            website: "https://www.travelodge.co.uk/hotels/361/Bath-Waterside-hotel",
            img: "images/hotels/bath_waterside_travelodge.jpg"
        },
        //... [and so on]
    ]
});
```

I have then used

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <div class = "options" ng-repeat="hotel in hotels">
        <div class = "option">
            <a ng-href={{hotel.website}}><img class="opt_img" ng-src={{hotel.img}}></a>
            <h3 class="centered" id="hotel_info">{{hotel.name}}<br>{{hotel.postcode | uppercase}}<br>Approx Price: {{hotel.price | currency:'&pound;'}}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This puts all the options one underneath each other. I can see why this is, as it doesn't create the options div around each set of 3 as I had done when making it manually. Is it possible to achieve this with the ng-repeat or do I need to rethink how I am doing it?

---

I am very new to web development so please make your answers beginner friendly, and bear with me if I have to ask for clarification. I am also open to people suggesting a better or simpler way of doing things, I merely used Codecademy's AngularJS course as a starting point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can easily be achieved by using css flex property

```
<div ng-controller="MainController" class="hotel-container">
    <div class = "options" ng-repeat="hotel in hotels">
        <div class = "option">
            <a ng-href={{hotel.website}}><img class="opt_img" ng-src={{hotel.img}}></a>
            <h3 class="centered" id="hotel_info">{{hotel.name}}<br>{{hotel.postcode | uppercase}}<br>Approx Price: {{hotel.price | currency:'&pound;'}}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 

.hotel-container {
   display: flex;
}
.options {
  width : 33.33%;
}
```

Read more flex property here : https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/

Comment: Thanks @DeblatonJean-Philippe :)

Comment: @lioness99a my pleasure :)

Answer (score -1):

**JS solution**

A really simple solution is to group your list into sublists of 3 elements:

```
 $scope.hotels = [
    [{
      name: 'Bailbrook House Hotel',
      postcode: "BA1 7JD",
      price: 0.00,
      website: "https://www.handpickedhotels.co.uk/bailbrookhouse",
      img: "images/hotels/BBH.jpg"
    }, {
      name: "Bath Central Travelodge",
      postcode: "BA1 2EB",
      price: 0.00,
      website: "https://www.travelodge.co.uk/hotels/75/Bath-Central-hotel",
      img: "images/hotels/bath_central_travelodge.jpg"
    }, {
      name: "Bath Waterside Travelodge",
      postcode: "BA2 4JP",
      price: 0.00,
      website: "https://www.travelodge.co.uk/hotels/361/Bath-Waterside-hotel",
      img: "images/hotels/bath_waterside_travelodge.jpg"
    }],
    //...
  ]
```

and then just add one more `ng-repeat` directive

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
  <div ng-repeat="group in hotels">
    <div class = "options" ng-repeat="hotel in group">
      <div class = "option">
        <a ng-href={{hotel.website}}><img class="opt_img" ng-src={{hotel.img}}></a>
        <h3 class="centered" id="hotel_info">{{hotel.name}}<br>{{hotel.postcode | uppercase}}<br>Approx Price: {{hotel.price | currency:'&pound;'}}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**CSS solution**

Another simple solution with CSS is to use `flex-direction: row` and then set the `flex` property accordingly on the elements. Here's a [code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yjmMzj) using the [bootstrap library](https://getbootstrap.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I had this thought at first but it seemed like a bad choice to me too especially as, if I decided I wanted to input a new item in the middle of a line, I would have to rework the whole array!

Comment: Yes, that's true. But you should compute the groups from the flat list anyway (and not rewrite it by hand every time it changes). Have a look at the CSS solution if you are more comfortable with that.